# Reverse a string program in java, having trouble in this error

Tags: java, string, methods, reverse

```
public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        System.out.println(reverse(array));
        String[] array = {"I","L","O","V","E","Y","O","U"};

    }

    public static String reverse(String phrase){

       for(int i = phrase.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
           System.out.println(phrase.charAt(i));

            }//end of loop

         return phrase;
        }//end of second class
    }//end of reverse class
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You can't use the array before it was defined. Also you can't use an array as parameter if the method want's a single `String`.

Comment: First instantiate: `String[] array = {"I","L","O","V","E","Y","O","U"};` and then use: `System.out.println(reverse(array));`

Comment: The reverse method is expecting a string but you appear to be trying to pass an array to it. Are you trying to reverse a string or an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are logical mistakes in your code. I am not going to tell you the solution but rather point out few things:

1. In main, you have to create string first and then pass it to your reverse method. String not an array, because your reverse method takes String as parameter.
2. In reverse method, you probably don't want to print reversed text, but rather create new string and return it. You will then print it in main.

Comment: Ty so much huge help!

Answer (score 1):

There were a fair few issues with the code you posted

1. Method return type was incorrect, you expected `String` but the return value is `String[]`
2. Parameter argument incorrect, as above
3. `phrase.length()` => `phrase.length`

I suggest, for a better understanding, to go [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm), and read the documentation of all of the methods you tried to use on the array.

Here is your code, working as I assume you'd expect it to:

```
public class Reverse
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] array = { "I", "L", "O", "V", "E", "Y", "O", "U" };

        System.out.println(reverse(array));

    }

    public static String[] reverse(String[] phrase)
    {
        for(int i = phrase.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            System.out.println(phrase[i]);
        }

        return phrase;

    }
}
```

Comment: imho should be a void method renamed to e.g. "reversePrint()", since the returned string is in fact not reversed and also not intended to be used.

Comment: I completely agree, but without much explanation by OP, I left my own assumptions out of it, and pieced it together how OP originally did.

Comment: Ty so much huge help!